# process vuetify elements from database

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to parse vuetify elements from a database.

simple example:

data: `<v-btn>Test</v-btn>`

template:

```
<div v-html="data"></div>
```

But this gives me:

"Test" without the button.

When inspecting the page i see:  `<v-btn>Test</v-btn>` in stead of the processed html.

Is there a way to use vuetify tags from a database?

Comment: `v-html` is used to render the HTML elements not a vue components.

Comment: oke. But is it possible to use vuetify tags from a database?

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html` is used to render the HTML elements and updates the element’s innerHTML. It will not work to render the `Vue` components.

*Is there a way to use vuetify tags from a database?* - Yes, You can achieve that by creating a component at runtime.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    dataStr: `<v-btn depressed color="primary">Primary</v-btn>`
  },
  computed: {
    myBtnComponent() {
      return Vue.component('myBtnComponent', {
        template: this.dataStr
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.9/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row
      align="center"
      justify="space-around"
    >
      <component :is="myBtnComponent" />
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```